# Inserting a column of values into a 2D Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to write an Array extension to insert a column of values to a 2D array. The problem is that I am not able to use self[index].insert(element, at) and not sure why. Here is what I have so far

```
extension Array where Element: Collection {
 
    mutating func insert(_ elements: Element, column: Int){
        for (index, element) in elements.enumerated() {
            self[index] // cannot do self[index].insert....
        }

    }
}
```

Here is what I am looking for:

lets say I have a 2D array of Ints (I could have Double, String,... any Type)

```
var data = [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
            [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
            [31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
            [41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
            [51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
            [61, 62, 63, 64,65]]
```

I would like to be able to call

```
data.insert([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], column: 0)
```

and the expected result would be:

```
[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
            [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
            [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
            [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
            [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
            [60, 61, 62, 63, 64,65]]
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Your tuple destructuring gets the parameters backwards. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated

Comment: @Jessy - OK, I get it, it was a mistake that I switched the tuple. But it still does not work. Have you tried? I don't think you should downvote for a simple oversight

Comment: in your extension self is immutable @matt answer uses a var

Comment: @AnderCover What so you mean by `self` is immutable? OP is extending array what is immutable is the Array element (collection)

Comment: @leo-dabus YES, my bad you're totally right and that is what I meant

Comment: but still, @matt answers uses a var and that what OP should do, but each elements of `self` in a var, mutate them and then mutate self

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to constrain your array's `Element` to `RangeReplaceableCollection` and make sure its Index is the same type of the Array Index:

---

```
extension Array where Element: RangeReplaceableCollection, Element.Index == Index {
    mutating func insert(_ elements: Element, column: Index) {
        for index in indices {
            self[index].insert(elements[index], at: column)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
var data = [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
            [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
            [31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
            [41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
            [51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
            [61, 62, 63, 64, 65]]

let colData = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
data.insert(colData, column: 0)
print(data)
```

This will print

> [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45], [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55], [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65]]

---

Expanding on that if you would like to append a column:

```
mutating func appendColumn(_ elements: Element) {
    for index in indices {
        self[index].insert(elements[index], at: self[index].endIndex)
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect. I was missing the RangeReplaceableCollection. Thank you!